# Is it possible to server to block ping

Tags: dns, ping

To be honest, I'm a little curious whether a server can block incoming ping. I tried to access a website while pinging it. I found out that my Ping gets `Request Timed Out` but I can still access the website perfectly.

I didn't find an error on my internet network and it was still quite fast. I can still ping Google DNS (`8.8.8.8`) but not with those website.

[PING Attempts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FefAv.png)

```
C:\Users\LOGIVAR TY 2>ping www.danamonline.com

Pinging www.danamonline.com [222.229.82.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 118.97.5.26: Destination net unreachable.
Reply from 118.97.5.26: Destination net unreachable.
Request timed out.
Reply from 118.97.5.26: Destination net unreachable.

Ping statistics for 222.229.82.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 3, Lost = 1 (25% loss),

C:\Users\LOGIVAR TY 2>ping 8.8.8.8

Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=119
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=119
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=119
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=119

Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 15ms, Maximum = 22ms, Average = 17ms
```

So the main question is:

> Can a server block all the pings from users? Is it possible to do it? If it's possible, then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Ping uses a transport method (By default, you can do other types of 'ping') called ICMP.

Accessing a website will normally use TCP, and port 80 or 443 (for secure connections).

Just because a website is listening on port 80 and 443, doesn't mean it's listening at all for ICMP. There's many valid (and a few invalid) reasons for blocking ICMP traffic, and as it's not required at all for http there is no reason why it'd effect your ability to browse the site.

Answer (score 3):

Ping response (as a security measure) can be blocked by changing a setting in the router 'Block ICMP Ping' (or similar) or by creating a rule/changing a setting in some firewall programs. For example, with Windows Firewall, an Inbound rule can be created to block ICMPv4 for all/specific ports.